# Flutter tabbar/tabview is not displaying the correct view after navigating to/from the page

Tags: flutter

I am having some issue getting the tabbar/TabBarView to work.

When I open the app and access the page containing the tab view , it works as designed. Meaning , clicking on each tab display the correct view content . However, if I select tab 2 and then go to another page in the app and then come back to this page with the tabs I see tab 1 selected but the contents shown is from tab 2. It seems the tabview is not getting updated.

What I want is every time I access the page it should display the first tab and content

Here is a snippet of my code. Please have a look and let me know how I can get it to work..please

```
    class MySettingPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
      _MySettingPageState createState() => _MySettingPageState();
    
    
    class _MySettingPageState extends State<MySettingPage>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController tabController;
    
    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
      }
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: const RappBar("my appbar"),
         body: if (auth.isLoggedIn) ...
                        [buildTabUI(myRModel.empId)] 
      )
    }
    
    Widget buildTabUI(String EmpID) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: ...
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                      child: TabBar(
                        controller: tabController,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            text: 'self service',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'settings',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: tabController,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: buildSelfServiceItems(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child: buildGeneralList(context),
                    )),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
                                   
    }
```

Image 1 & 2 are the original tab. Navigating back and forth within the tab work.

Image 3: I selected tab 2 and navigate away form the page, when I navigate back to the page with the tab this is shown.

As you can see , the correct tab is selected but the view is for tab 2. I would like tab 1 to be shown with tab 1 content

---

[image: Tab 1 view]

[image: Tab 2 view]

[image: Tab 1 view after navigation back to page, Tab 2 was selected before navigating away]

Comment: Where was `tabController` declared?

Comment: tabController is define in  the state controller.I updated the code

Comment: Can you try changing with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin to with TickerProviderStateMixin

Comment: Changed to TickerProviderStateMixin but same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to save the index of the tab after you navigate to a different screen. The way I would do it though is as follows:

Create int variable:

```
int tabIndex = 0;
```

In your TabController initState you can add the attribute `initialIndex`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this, initialIndex: tabIndex);
  }
```

So when you navigate to next page, you add `.then` to retrieve the value when returning from another page.
You can then pass the tabIndex value when you return from the other page:

Navigating away:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,'example').then((value){
     setState((){
       tabIndex = value;
     });
});
```

Navigating back:

```
Navigator.pop(context, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you Texv,
the issue is that tab is getting change but the tabview content is not getting update.

Comment: how do you handle navigating back to the tab page?

Comment: So there buttonnavigationbar (see image 1) that change the pages.  All I want is to go to the tap 1 when I click on the page. I am able to get tab 1 but the content does not match